# Triggering character animation with collider C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to trigger an animation on character when a surgical instrument collides with a 3d brain . I have tried almost everything but I can't seem to trigger the animation upon collision.

Additionally the brain is soft body and has box collider attached to it with the is Trigger enabled. The surgical instrument is a rigid body that has box collider and obi collider but the is Trigger is disable.

Please help I have been stuck for days now, Please.

I have tried to used bool and trigger parameters to fire up the animation ,also I have tried to fire  up the animation directly without an parameter upon collision

```
public GameObject character;
Animator anim;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if(col.gameObjectComparaTag("brain")) 
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("is stroking")
        Debug.Log("there is collision")
    }
} 

void Start()
{
    anim = character.GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

This should fire up and animation when the collision between the brain and instruments

Comment: what library is this? unity?

Comment: using system.Collection; using UnityEngine; using system.Collection.Generic;...I am not sure if that is what you mean

Comment: `if(col.gameObjectComparaTag("brain")) `, did you meant `if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("brain")) `?

Comment: It would help to see some screens of your setup and the animation controller

Comment: Are you sure it is a trigger not a collider? is the OnTriggerEnter fired? Move the debug to find out